# Checking group of boxes in an indented tree

Tags: d3.js

Staring from [previously posted code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708047/drawing-a-collapsible-indented-tree-with-d3/27726912#27726912) I'd like check branch boxes when one clicks on the upper box. For instance, on the picture below, I would like that checking the `BRE` box, check the five checkboxes of the tree branch, and conversely, unchecking `BRE` would uncheck the five children.

[image]

To do so, I made a few changes in the code:

```
// On click, check the corresponding box, select it as well as its children (recursively)
function check(d) {
    d.Selected = !d.Selected;
    d3.select(this).style("opacity", boxStyle(d));
    if (d.children) {
        // mark children recursively
        for(n in d.children) {
            checkBox(d.children[n], d.Selected);
        }
    }
    console.log(d);
    update(d);
}

function checkBox(d, checked) {
    d.Selected = checked;
}
```

As one can check in the console, items are properly `Selected`, the clicked box is properly checked, but children are not although I forced updating the drawing with the update function used to update after collapsing/expending.

Collapsing, hence expending the tree shows that everything is in place to properly draw the tree, it seems that it's not updated (redrawn from source) after the `BRE` box have been checked.

Is there something in the main code that prevent redrawing when branches have not been collapsed or expended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only apply the style:

```
 .attr("style", function(d) { return "opacity: "+boxStyle(d) });
```

on the `nodeEnter` selection in your update.  You need to apply on the `node` selection to update:

```
 node.selectAll("path:nth-child(3)")
   .attr("style", function(d) { return "opacity: "+boxStyle(d) });
```

The selector here is a little funny.  Since you have multiple `paths` at in each node I had to find it by it's child position.

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wTcTH6llvhKlmlMpqw5o?p=preview).

**Note**, two things:

1.) This is not truly recursive and it only "checks" one child level down.

2.) It'll only check the children if the node is expanded.

Here's a [new version which](http://plnkr.co/edit/40DISsOlpSOeCQhzkWEC?p=preview) solves those issues:

```
// Toggle check box on click.
function check(d) {
    d.Selected = !d.Selected;
    if (d.children || d._children) {
        // mark children recursively
        for(var n in d.children) {
          check(d.children[n]);
        }
        for(n in d._children) {
           check(d._children[n]);
        }
    }
}

function recurCheck(d){
  check(d);
  update(d);
}
```

Comment: You're correct, it's no more recursive, this was my intension, and it was truly recursive, my problem at that time was that changing the node that was not working in deeper levels, probably because there is no link between the d3 node objects and the node data or that I don't know how to link between the two. I looked at your example code, it seems not to check deeper nodes, even when expanded. The fact that only expanded nodes are checked is ok with me, since the data is marked selected, I expect them to be checked at while expending.

Comment: Your new version adresses the previous issues, but it seem to "xor" check nodes, I'd like to check unchecked and leave checked as is while clicking an upper level node. I should be able to manage that. Thanks for your help.